# Which library to import in Python to read data from an Excel file, for automation testing using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

Which library to import in Python to read data from an Excel file, I want to store different `xpaths` in Excel file for automation testing using Selenium?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) library is what you are looking for to read excel files. And to write, you can use [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Comment: Actually like in java there is a file excelreader.java in apache POI like that , I want to read data from excel file for xpaths, so I am looking a file which can read data in python

Comment: `xlrd` does that. Install it using `pip install xlrd`. Then you can import it in your projects and use it to read excel files like `book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)`. From that you can access sheets, rows, and columns.

Comment: @Kidus__ If you have an example of reading data in python and selenium can u please paste it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can Google for examples. But here's one on xlrd: https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/

Comment: Thank you @Kidus for help. I will use this example blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/...

Comment: For xlwt, there's a quick start guide on the download page I linked.

Comment: Which download page ur telling i didnot get @kidus

Comment: The one in the answer. I'll give you here anyway. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Comment: Ya I got now.Thank you @kidus

Comment: sure i will do @kidus

Answer (score 1):

You may use **XlsxWriter**. It is a Python module for writing files in Excel.
**xlutils** is also very useful collection of utilities for automating excel sheet operations.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).